# Windows::Web::Http::HttpClient - Renegotiate SSL handshake

Tags: c++, ssl, windows-phone-8.1, c++-cx

As part of the my Windows phone app, I use [Windows::Web::Http::HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httpclient.aspx) to post requests to the server. I tried -

```
void sendRequest(HttpRequestMessage^ httpReqMsg)
{
    HttpBaseProtocolFilter^ httpFilter = ref new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
    httpFilter->CacheControl->WriteBehavior = HttpCacheWriteBehavior::NoCache;

    HttpClient^ httpClient = ref new HttpClient(httpFilter);

    try
    {
        // Post the request
        auto httpProgress = httpClient->SendRequestAsync(httpReqMsg);

        // Handle the http progress and it's response messages
        // ...
    }
    catch(Exception^ ex)
    {
        // ...
    }

} // httpFilter, httpClient are auto released
```

When `httpFilter, httpClient` falls out of scope, I expect underlying sockets and memory resources should be released. During the call `HttpClient::SendRequestAsync`, I see SSL negotiation happening for the first time. Any further calls to `sendRequest` function, isn't triggering full handshake.

I amn't allowed to load any DLLs to explicity clear the SSL cache ([SslEmptyCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380388%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). Isn't my assumption correct that full handshake should happen on every call to `sendRequest` function ? If not, how to achieve full SSL handshake ? Thanks.

Comment: How did you come to that conclusion? Are all requests going through a single connection?

Comment: As part of handler for `httpProgress`, I log the messages. On call to `sendRequest`, I see the log **Negotiating SSL** coming from OS. In the subsequent calls, I don't see it. And even in wireshark, I don't see full SSL handshake.